# NextJS is rendering markdown frontmatter

Tags: next.js, markdown

In our NextJS app, we have markdown files like so

`markdown.mdx`

```
---
title: Privacy policy
description: The privacy of your data...
---

# Privacy policy
```

Which we pull into a page using

`page.tsx`

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Markdown from './markdown.mdx';

export default function Page({ postData }) {
  return <>
    <Head>
      <title>{Markdown.title}</title>
    </Head>
    <Markdown />
  </>
}
```

However, this is outputting all the markdown frontmatter to the html

```
<h2>title: Privacy policydescription: The privacy of your data...</h2>
<h1>Privacy policy</h1>
```

Here's how our project is set up:

`next.config.mjs`

```
import nextMdx from '@next/mdx'
import remarkFrontmatter from 'remark-frontmatter';
import remarkMdxFrontmatter from 'remark-mdx-frontmatter';

const withMdx = nextMdx({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    jsx: true,
    remarkPlugins: [remarkFrontmatter, remarkMdxFrontmatter],
    rehypePlugins: []
  },
})

// export default nextMdx(nextConfig)({
export default withMdx({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
  },
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    mdxRs: true,
  },
  pageExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx']
})
```

And this are the relevant packages:

```
    "next": "^13.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "remark-frontmatter": "^4.0.1",
    "remark-mdx-frontmatter": "^2.1.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

The same problem and attempted solution for me turned out to be fixed by disabling:

```
    mdxRs: true,
```

Set this to false and you'll find it works as expected